# Python giving UnicodeWarning when calling remove() on a list containing unicode strings

Tags: python, string, list, unicode

I have two lists containing unicode strings. I'm trying to remove every element from availablesongs that also appears in recentsongs.

The following code is causing the problem (exception clause commented out for debugging):

```
for x in recentsongs:
    #try:
        availablesongs.remove(x)
    #except ValueError:
    #   pass
```

This code works fine when the lists contain ASCII-only strings, but when characters from other languages are introduced, it fails:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  availablesongs.remove(x)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The error is coming from the remove() function itself, which has me stumped. How can I work around this?

Comment: [Tooo lazy to post a full answer.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Convert everything to unicode, or convert everything to the same encoding. Don't mix unicode and encoded text.

Comment: [Thanks...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149850/python-giving-unicodewarning-when-calling-remove-on-a-list-containing-unicode#comment13016466_10149850) this [page](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) did indeed help me solve my problem. The function "to_unicode_or_bust" works, I just wrote an additional function to iterate it over the arrays beforehand.

Comment: An important thing that I have found is that os.listdir() doesn't always return strings with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.listdir() was causing some of my problems because it sometimes returns unicode strings and sometimes doesn't. The function [to_unicode_or_bust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149850/python-giving-unicodewarning-when-calling-remove-on-a-list-containing-unicode#comment13016466_10149850) works to fix the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
list(set(availablesongs)-set(recentsongs))
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it seems as though it would lose the ordering of the lists, which would be bad if the ordering was important.